# Idiom for "reducing" a list with another list of methods

Tags: python, reduce, idioms

I came across a situation where I wanted to "reduce" one list of integers by another list of methods.

```
>>> import operator
>>> 
>>> OPS = [operator.add, operator.sub, operator.add]
>>> nums = [1,2,3,4]
>>> 
>>> OPS[2](OPS[1](OPS[0](nums[0],nums[1]),nums[2]),nums[3])
4
```

for loop:

```
>>> result = nums[0]
>>> for i in range(1,len(nums)):
...     result = OPS[i-1](result,nums[i])
... 
>>> print result
4
```

"queues":

```
>>> result = nums.pop(0)
>>> while nums:
...     result = OPS.pop(0)(result, nums.pop(0))
... 
>>> print result
4
```

If I just wanted to apply one method to the list of numbers, for example operator.add, I could use reduce.

```
>>> reduce(operator.add, [1,2,3,4])
10
```

Is there something similar for combining two lists, one of operators and another of operands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

```
>>> OPS = [operator.add, operator.sub, operator.add]
>>> nums = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print reduce(lambda x, y: y[0](x, y[1]), zip(OPS, nums[1:]), nums[0])
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Ignacio's solution, but with iterators and izip, and only for Python < 3.x:

```
>>> import operator
>>> import itertools
>>> 
>>> ops = [operator.add, operator.sub, operator.add]
>>> nums = iter([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> 
>>> print reduce(lambda a, (f, b): f(a, b), itertools.izip(ops, nums), next(nums))
4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> it = iter(OPS)
>>> reduce(lambda *a: next(it)(*a), nums)
4
```